# Joining strings python after sql query

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an sql query that returns two columns.  I need to join those together while mapping the results into files.

I attempted this:

```
results = sqlContext.sql(query)

results.map(lambda p: ('::'.join(str(p.title),str(p.genres))).repartition(10).saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2]))
```

This does not give an error, it just quits executing for some reason.

I have gotten it to work when the query only returns one column with this line:

```
results.map(lambda p: str(p.title)).repartition(10).saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
```

How would I join these two columns using the delimiter `'::'`?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and after every operation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was simply a problem of not enough parenthesis.  I needed

```
results.map(lambda p: '::'.join(str(p.title), str(p.genres))).repartition(10).saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
```

instead of

```
results.map(lambda p: ('::'.join(str(p.title),str(p.genres))).repartition(10).saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2]))
```